# Plugin already initialized

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am doing plugin for teleport between servers in bungeecord. Suddenly, i don't know how, but error starts occur. Can you tell me, where is the problem? Thank you for your response.

Full Stacktrace:

org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin already initialized!
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:139) ~[spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:334) ~[spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:253) [spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_15_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:351) [spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:203) [spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:784) [spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin already initialized!
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.initialize(PluginClassLoader.java:178) ~[spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.(JavaPlugin.java:52) ~[spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at pl.piotrek.main.Main.(Main.java:9) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:166) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:404) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:591) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.(PluginClassLoader.java:72) ~[spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:135) ~[spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Initial initialization
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.initialize(PluginClassLoader.java:181) ~[spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.(JavaPlugin.java:52) ~[spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at pl.piotrek.main.Main.(Main.java:9) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:166) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:404) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:591) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.(PluginClassLoader.java:72) ~[spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:135) ~[spigot-1.15.2.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        ... 6 more

Main class:

```
package pl.piotrek.main;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import pl.piotrek.commands.ServersCommand;
import pl.piotrek.events.ServersGuiListener;
import pl.piotrek.gui.Gui;
import pl.piotrek.message.channel.PluginMessagingListener;
import pl.piotrek.message.command.ConnectCommand;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    private static Main instance;
    public static Main getInstance() { return instance; }
    public void setInstance(Main instance) { Main.instance = instance; }
    public Gui gui;
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        System.out.println("Enabled TeleportationUtils v1.0.0");
        setInstance(this);
        registerCommands();
        registerListener();
        this.getServer().getMessenger().registerOutgoingPluginChannel(this, "BungeeCord");
        this.getServer().getMessenger().registerIncomingPluginChannel(this, "BungeeCord", new PluginMessagingListener());
        gui = new Gui();
    }
    public void registerCommands() {
        getCommand("connect").setExecutor(new ConnectCommand());
        getCommand("servers").setExecutor(new ServersCommand());
    }
    public void registerListener() {
        this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new ServersGuiListener(), this);
    }
}
```

Plugin.yml:

```
name: TeleportationUtils
version: 1.0.0
main: pl.piotrek.main.Main
api-version: 1.15
commands:
  connect:
    aliases: [cnt]
    description: Connect to another sevrer command
  servers:
    aliases: [svr]
    description: Server menu command for teleport between servers
permissions:
  commands:
   connect:
```

Comment: Is that the whole stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

Your stack trace shows that your plugin is initially initialized at `pl.piotrek.main.Main.<init>(Main.java:9)` and then it's trying to be initialized again at the same point. It is very likely that you have the same plugin twice in your plugins folder, probably under a different name.

Have a look through your server's plugin folder and find the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

you most likely have "extends JavaPlugin" in 2 classes. you can only have this in your Main class. What you should do instead is

```
    private final Main plugin;
    public className(Main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }
```

in your other classes, and use `plugin.whatever` to access things you normally only could in your Main class.

Also in your plugin.yml, you have

```
permissions:
  commands:
   connect:
```

this does not follow Bukkit's permission standards which can be found [here](https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Understanding_Permissions#:%7E:text=Bukkit%20allows%20permissions%20to%20be,the%20child%20node%20permissions%20too.).

And when naming your packages, its best to put the plugin name in there. something like `pl.piotrek.TeleportationUtils.main.Main` so if you have more then one of your plugins in the server, it won't cause issues.